# Demo using Aurelia- can not install jspm

Tags: aurelia

I following this link https://github.com/rmourato/Mvc5-Aurelia

[image]

I can not install jspm and run project

I already install nodejs

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: If you're using the Aurelia-CLI, you need to be using NPM only for packages. Not jspm.

Comment: You need to install npm and Git before installing jspm

Answer (score 0):

Next to nodejs (which installs npm) you also need to install *gulp* and *jspm*.

So change into the Mvc5-Aurelia/Aurelia directory and run:

```
npm install
npm install -g gulp
npm install -g jspm
```

More details here: https://github.com/rmourato/Mvc5-Aurelia/tree/master/Mvc5-Aurelia/Aurelia under **Running the App**

After that you can run `gulp watch`